# Highlight current row when dragging over a silverlight datagrid

Tags: datagrid, silverlight-4.0, drag-and-drop

Using Silverlight 4, I have a DataGrid.  I am grabbing a file from Windows Explorer and dragging it over the grid (I set AllowDrop=true on my DataGrid).  When I drag over the grid I would like to highlight the row that the mouse is currently over (I want to point out to the user which row the file will be dropped if they release the mouse button at that time).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

this can be done by attaching Mouseover events .. Can't it?